# JSON PHP formatting Jackson parsing POJO

Tags: php, codeigniter, jackson, pojo

I am using CodeIgniter for some small REST WS,
and can not get a properly (as viewed from Jackson parser point of view)
formatted JSON output. For Jackson to do it, the output needs to be something like:

```
{ "recipes": 
    [ 
        {
            "name":"Recipe 1",
            "id":"8aecfd9b2fa26e83012fa298c2a50017",
            "recipe":"1 Lorem ipsum...",
        }, 
        { 
            "name":"Recipe 2",
            "id":"8aecfd9b2fa26e83012fa298c2a90018",
            "recipe":"2 Lorem ipsum...",
        },
        {
            "name": "Recipe 3",
            "id":"8aecfd9b2fa26e83012fa298c2ae0019",
            "recipe":"3 Lorem ipsum...",
        } 
    ]
}
```

And using the code in CodeIgniter controller like:

```
        $allEecipes['recipes'] = array(
                    array('name' => 'Recipe 1', 'id' => '8aecfd9b2fa26e83012fa298c2a50017', 'recipe' => '1 Lorem ipsum...'),
                    array('name' => 'Recipe 2', 'id' => '128aecfd9b226e83012fa298c2a50017', 'recipe' => '1 Lorem ipsum...'),
                    array('name' => 'Recipe 3', 'id' => '34ecfd9b2fa26e83012fa298c2a50017', 'recipe' => '1 Lorem ipsum...'),
        );      

        $this->response($allEecipes, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
```

I get the following JSON output:

```
[
  [
    {
      "name": "Recipe 1",
      "id": "8aecfd9b2fa26e83012fa298c2a50017",
      "recipe": "1 Lorem ipsum..."
    },
    {
      "name": "Recipe 2",
      "id": "128aecfd9b226e83012fa298c2a50017",
      "recipe": "1 Lorem ipsum..."
    },
    {
      "name": "Recipe 3",
      "id": "34ecfd9b2fa26e83012fa298c2a50017",
      "recipe": "1 Lorem ipsum..."
    }
  ]
]
```

Notice the brackets, and the missing name for an array.
How to get things right? I suppose the PHP encode_to_json is
doing it's job correctly.

**EDITED:**
Still no luck, after adding class like

```
class Eecipes
{
    public $recipes;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }
}
```

And creating it like

```
    $allEecipes = new Eecipes();
    $allEecipes-> recipes = array(
        array('name' => 'Recipe 1', 'id' => '8aecfd9b2fa26e83012fa298c2a50017', 'recipe' => '1 Lorem ipsum...'),
        array('name' => 'Recipe 2', 'id' => '128aecfd9b226e83012fa298c2a50017', 'recipe' => '1 Lorem ipsum...'),
        array('name' => 'Recipe 3', 'id' => '34ecfd9b2fa26e83012fa298c2a50017', 'recipe' => '1 Lorem ipsum...'),
        );
$this->response($allEecipes, 200);
```

The output I get is

```
{
  "recipes": {
    "0": {
      "name": "Recipe 1",
      "id": "8aecfd9b2fa26e83012fa298c2a50017",
      "recipe": "1 Lorem ipsum..."
    },
    "1": {
      "name": "Recipe 2",
      "id": "128aecfd9b226e83012fa298c2a50017",
      "recipe": "1 Lorem ipsum..."
    },
    "2": {
      "name": "Recipe 3",
      "id": "34ecfd9b2fa26e83012fa298c2a50017",
      "recipe": "1 Lorem ipsum..."
    }
  }
}
```

So, still not as needed. No angled brackets **[**, and the numbers are not needed.
And the result in online JSON viewer shows the difference, too

The good:
http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/7034/goodj.jpg

and the bad:
http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/3389/badrk.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try encoding your result yourself with [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode)
and then send the result ?
Look at the flag options of json_encode, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT might help you

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that too, slightly better results, but still not as expected...  I then do get similar, but curly brackets on the outer level, and I need [

Comment: $allEecipes needs to be an object then, and you need to do like so : $allEecipes->recipes = array();

Comment: Tried that too, check my post EDIT

Comment: BUT, the code with an instance of a class(@NeeL) COMBINED with json_encode WITHOUT Force_Object, gave a preferable solution. Tnx Neel, your hints were helpful.